# Trasformar consulta mysql em lista

Tags: php, jquery, html, array

Estou fazendo uma consulta em um banco que retorna uma lista de usuários, os quais estou imprimindo em uma tabela.

Gostaria de transformar essa consulta em uma lista para depois inserir esses usuários em outra tabela

Faço a consulta assim:

```
 $sql= mysqli_query($conect,"select u.username as username,c.fullname from
  mdl_course c left outer join mdl_context cx on c.id = cx.instanceid
  left outer join mdl_role_assignments ra on cx.id = ra.contextid
  left outer join mdl_user u on ra.userid = u.id 
  where ra.roleid in (5) and u.username like '$usuario'
  and cx.contextlevel = 50 and c.id = 5 order by u.username") 
  or die(mysqli_error());

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){  

  }
```

Gostaria de salvar `username`, `firstname`, `lastname` e `email`.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Adicione na pergunta o select e quais colunas da sua tabela você quer recuperar na query.

Comment: Pronto @DiegoFelipe

Answer (score 3):

Uma boa maneira de fazer isso é criando uma classe `Usuario`, assim você guarda "Usuários" dentro de uma lista e não precisa ficar criando array bidimensional para que não misture os usuários retornados.

```
class Usuario {

    private $username;
    private $firstname;
    private $lastname;
    private $email;

    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername($username) {
        this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getFirstname() {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname($firstname) {
        this->firstname = $firstname;
    }

    public function getLastname() {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    public function setLastname($lastname) {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
    }

    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $email;
    } 
}
```

Salve isso em um arquivo `php` diferente e o nomeie como `Usuario.php`, e faça o include do arquivo no seu código do banco.

Depois, basta iniciar um objeto, recuperar os dados do select e salvar no array:

```
include_once(Usuarios.php);//altere de acordo com o caminho onde salvou

...

$arr = Array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){  

$user = new Usuario();
$user->setUsername($row['username']);
$user->setFirstname($row['firstname']);
$user->setLastname($row['lastname']);
$user->setEmail($row['email']);
$arr[] = $user;

}
```

E para exibir/recuperar os usuarios do `array`:

```
foreach($arr as $user){
  echo $user->getUsername();
  echo $user->getFirstname();
  echo$user->getLastname();
  echo $user->getEmail();
}
```

Caso não queira ou não saiba trabalhar com classes e objetos, outra solução pra não bagunçar vários usuários em uma lista, seria usar um `array` bidimensional:

```
    $usuarios = Array();

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){  

   $user = Array();
   $user['username'] = $row['username'];
   $user['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
   $user['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
   $user['email'] = $row['email'];
   $usuarios[] = $user;
   }
```

Para exibir um usuario, basta usar um `foreach` dessa forma:

```
foreach($usuarios as $user){
  echo $user['username'];
  echo $user['firstname'];
  echo$user['lastname'];
  echo $user['email'];
}
```

**Referências:**

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/503939-pegar-valor-retornado-no-mysqli-fetch-array/

Comment: Dependendo do caso você pode criar uma função com um parâmetro, por exemplo `listaUsuario('completo')` ou `listaUsuario('simples')`  ele seria responsável por definir quais campos a consulta deve retornar, ai são eliminadas as atribuições, `$user['username'] = $row['username']` e demais por apenas `$usuarios[] = $user`

Comment: @rray pra falar a verdade eu optaria pelo primeiro modo, usando objetos, por ser mais direto kkk. Mas não entendi seu racioncinio, de qualquer modo(listando todas as colunas do select ou apenas algumas), não teria que ser informado quais devem ser recuperadas do `$row`?

Comment: Acho que entendi errado a pergunta, tive a impressão que a consulta retornaria mais que os quatros campos solicitados e que OP não quisesses esses campos a mais, para criar duas consultas ou duas funções o código que sugeri foi esse: LOL mas acho que não tem haver com pergunta xD.

Comment: `function listar($tipo='simples'){
 $colunas = ['simples' => 'c_txt_nome as nome, c_txt_email as email, c_txt_senha as senha', 'completo' => 'c_txt_nome, c_txt_sobrenome, c_txt_email, c_txt_email, c_dt_nascimento, c_txt_telefone, c_txt_endereco'];
 $index = !isset($colunas[$tipo]) ? $colunas['completo'] : $colunas[$tipo];
 
 $sql = sprintf("SELECT %s FROM tabela WHERE .... ", $index);
 
 $res = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
 $lista = [];
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
  $lista[] = $row;
 }
 return $lista;
}
listar('completo');`